# Specifying Spearate Build in CMAKE

Tags: cmake, clion

I am interested in building/compiling specific projects from my root project using cmake. For example if I have the following file structure:

```
root
    project1
       include
       src
    project2
       include
       src
```

How can I specify in cmake/clion to only build project1? Thanks in advance

Comment: IMHO this is rather a question about CLion than CMake. You just need to [select the specific build target](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.1/quick-cmake-tutorial.html#d93235e341) (rather than 'Build All') in the IDE.

Comment: Yes, thank you! But, this builds all the projects and executes them separately. I was wondering if there is a way to build separately?